# Showing week number in title bar

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to show the week number in `fc-toolbar-title`? The default title shows "25 – 30 jan. 2021" and I would like to add " - Week 4" or dynamically the value set by the parameters `weekNumbers` and `weekText`.

The following shows "maandag 25 – zaterdag 30 januari 2021", so the week number is still missing:

```
titleFormat: {
   month: 'long',
   year: 'numeric',
   day: 'numeric',
   weekday: 'long',
   week: 'short'
 }
```

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason why in the documentation: "This flag ('week') cannot be combined with any other flags!". But why?!

Comment: Delete this answer and add it to your initial question

Comment: `But why?!`...you'd better ask the people who wrote FullCalendar that question, we cannot tell you what their logic was.